# react-native statusBar with expo on iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, statusbar, expo

I was trying to change the color of the `statusBar` on my react-native app.

I am working with `expo` and on their documentation they are just specifying to add :
`"androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#2E1D59"
    }`

that works fine with android, but they did not mention how to do so with iOS statusBar.

Anyone has an idea about this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't change the color of the iOS status bar.

You can use the React Native [StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html) module to either hide it, or set the text color to light (white) or dark (black).

You can just drop the component in your app's root component:

```
 <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I hope they will add a support to that in the future.

Comment: It's not an Expo or React Native limitation. iOS doesn't allow you to set a status bar color at all - no apps can.

Comment: Actually there is a trick!
The react-native header is behind the iOS statusBar, so if you set the color of the header to whatever you want, you can make feel the user like it has a color.

Comment: @jevakallio thats not completely true? In Swift there is no problem to change the statusbar color.

Comment: @user2236165 you can set the text to be white or black, and you can position an element behind the status bar to make it appear a certain color, but is there an actually API for setting the status bar color itself?

Comment: @jevakallio I may be wrong, but based on some of the examples it looks like the color can be set explicitly on iOS? https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-13-how-to-change-status-bar-color-1431c185e845

Comment: <StatusBar style="light" /> is the latest syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the background color of the `StatusBar` itself, but your components can fill the space and you set the color on the component. Then use the `StatusBar` component to tell iOS to change the text color.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Appearance, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [colorScheme, setColorScheme] = useState(Appearance.getColorScheme());

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(({ colorScheme }) => {
      setColorScheme(colorScheme);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'black' : 'white' }}>
      <StatusBar style={colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'} />
      {/* Your app content */}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the following package:
`npm i ios-status-bar`

I usually end up using doing this.

```
<IOSStatusBar color={"rgba(255, 173, 25, 1.0)"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the StatusBar background color in iOS. However, theres a work-around. You have to define the background color of the header in the Stack Navigator of @react-navigation/stack

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

//Pages
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

const AppLoad = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppLoad.Navigator initialRouteName='Dashboard'>
          <AppLoad.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}
              options={{
                headerTitle: null,
                headerLeft: null,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#0891b2',
                  shadowColor: 'transparent',
                  elevation: 0,
                  height: 48,
                },
              }}/>
        </AppLoad.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
```

[image: iPhone 14 Expo Go]